# How to make sure interrupt can not be generated between specific Code Snippet?

Tags: c, dos, interrupt-handling, watcom

I have one question about the timing of interrupt generation between code snippets...

@ "example" code

```
1. ...
2. assign value to global variable  // 0/1 means invalid/valid
3. set H/W register via memory-mapped IO method  // 0 means completed
```

@ "example" ISR code

```
a. ...
b. if(global value is valid && H/W register is "0") then count++;
```

- One thing to note: *After H/W register is set, its value will be 0 when "completion" !*

***My question is***: if the interrupt is generated between **2** and **3**, then count will be increased by one because step **3** is not done yet(value is 0)... And if 
exchange **2** and **3**, then it is possible count will NOT be increased by 1 because even HW register is 0(after some time, completed) global variable is 0 !

My first idea is: is it possible **2** and **3** can be "tied together" in some way and interrupt is not allowed to be generated until **3** is done ?

- I use watcom c and test in DOS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either inline assembly, or a call to an external function written in assembler, to invoke the x86 `CLI` and `STI` instructions for disabling and enabling interrupts.

Comment: you mean `cli+2+3+sti` can be written as inline assembly or external assembly function ? Does that means interrupt will not assert during these assembly codes ?

Comment: As long as the `cli` takes place in assembly that runs before steps 2 and 3, and the `sti` takes place in assembly that runs after steps 2 and 3, you should be good.

Comment: Finally I just mask the interrupt device used(instead of masking "all" maskable interrupts) to make other interrupts work well by configuring 8259s...

Comment: The above method is OK with pin-based interrupt mode. But if using MSI(Message Signaled Interrupt) how to "enable/disable" MSI for this purpose ?

Comment: Huh? Pin-based versus MSI should only matter at the hardware level. Clearing the interrupt flag (via `CLI`) prevents the cpu from acting on any interrupts.

Comment: As I know sti/cli configures IF(Interrupt flag) and determines whether or not the CPU will handle maskable hardware interrupts. Here the maskable interrupts means 8259's IRQ 0~15, right ? But for MSI, this kind of interrupt is issued via CPU's local apic and does not route 8259. Thus I guess sti/cli can not "block" MSI...